# How do I change the color of this pictures backround, keeping the effects like the purple shining?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: T-shirt design]
This pic is for a shirt print gift and I'm trying to figutre out how I could make the backroung white in Adobe Photoshop CC. The effect looks fairly complex so I've no idea how to go around it, only way I think this is possible is by reproducing the effect, which I also don't know how to do.

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude here, but it's the truth.  If you don't know how to create the purple glow, teaching you how to cut out the background is going to get too complicated.  Doing it properly will involve using the pen tool and then creating a mask from that path.  Then you'll have to recreate the purple glow after the cat and book are cut out.  It's too broad for what we do on this site.

Comment: It's fine I was just looking up sites where people could help get this done, I've no idea what I'm doing just tryna get the shirt to look fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2):

You need to use whatever selection methods you're most comfortable with to select the cat, book, and text. Invert that selection and fill with your new color (on a new layer). Then use blending options to bring back the purple glow.

This was cropped in about 20 seconds using the Polygonal Lasso. If you take your time the Polygonal Lasso tool will be your best bet here as a beginner trying to get this done. I used it for years before ever touching Pen Tool. If you do have some experience with Pen Tool though it'll work even better. The text I just used Magic Wand.

[image]